# Ruby mysql gem 'reconnect' object variable

Tags: mysql, ruby, reconnect

I am encountering the 'mysql has gone away' error in Ruby after a certain amount of time that the script has been running.

I want to try to tell the mysql gem to auto-reconnect when the connection is lost.

My current code looks like the following:

```
def self.connect()
  begin
    if !@@dbh.nil?
      self.disconnect
    end
    @@dbh = Mysql.real_connect(@@server, @@user, @@pass, @@db)
    puts "[+] Connected to the " + @@db + " database with user '" + @@user + "'"
  rescue Mysql::Error => e
    # log error
  end
end
```

The following guide [0] says that the mysql gem has a 'reconnect' object variable, however, I am unsure of how to use it within my code.

How do I implement this option into the code above?

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

[0] http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/

**EDIT ---**

OK. I think I have figured it out.

I need to add `@@dbh.reconnect = true` after the `@@dbh = Mysql.real_connect(@@server, @@user, @@pass, @@db)` line.

Note: According to a 'nice' chapy on IRC the mysql gem may not be the best Ruby gem to use.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're leaning so heavily on `@@` class variables? This is unconventional to the point that the Stack Overflow syntax highlighter doesn't even know what to make of them.

Comment: I'm not sure what the reasoning was. The database class was written by someone else. I'll see if I can change it. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting on a new project, the [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/) gem is the way to go. It's an enormous improvement over the old version.

An attempt to Ruby-ize your example is:

```
def connect
  begin
    if (@dbh)
      self.disconnect
    end

    @dbh = Mysql.real_connect(@server, @user, @pass, @db)
    puts "[+] Connected to the #{@db} database with user '#{@user}'"
  rescue Mysql::Error => e
    # log error
  end
end
```

The reason for using traditional `@` variables is you can use `attr_accessor` if you design your interface properly.

It's better to use a singleton instance than to wreck around with a singleton class. For instance:

```
class MyApp
  def self.db
    @db ||= Database.new
  end

  class Database
    # Instance methods like initialize, connect, disconnect, etc.
  end
 end
```

You can use this like:

```
MyApp.db.connect
```

The advantage of using an instance of a class instead of a class directly is you can support more than one connection at a time.

Comment: P.S. the mysql2 gem looks much nicer, I'll investigate to see how much work it wil be to implement. Thanks again!